# Preventing variable overwriting in recursive Makefiles

Tags: makefile

I have the following project structure:

```
project/
  - Makefile
  - foo/
    - foo.mk
  - bar/
    - bar.mk
```

Contents of `Makefile`:

```
.PHONY: all foo bar

all: foo bar

include foo/foo.mk
include bar/bar.mk
```

Contents of `foo/foo.mk`:

```
SOME_VAR=foo

foo:
        @echo $(SOME_VAR)
```

Contents of `bar/bar.mk`:

```
SOME_VAR=bar

bar:
        @echo $(SOME_VAR)
```

Running the command `make` in yields the output

```
bar
bar
```

The observed output is easy to explain: variables in recipes are expanded only when the rule is executed, so when `SOME_VAR` is overwritten in `bar.mk` the rule for `foo` prints `bar`. Is there any way of preventing this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use [target-specific variable values](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific).

Change your sub-makefiles to

```
bar: SOME_VAR=bar
bar:
    @echo $(SOME_VAR)
```

```
foo: SOME_VAR=foo
foo:
    @echo $(SOME_VAR)
```

Recursive make will also work

```
all:
    $(MAKE) -C foo -f foo.mk
    $(MAKE) -C bar -f bar.mk
```

Comment: Target-specific variables don't work for my use case but recursive make does.